# CorePlot plotting graph with the data retrieved from web service

Tags: ios, iphone, asynchronous, graph, core-plot

I am drawing a graph with the help of coreplot in which multiple line graphs are there. I have multiple urls to get the data from the web service. The problem is that I have implemented this with the help of synchronous web service call but it freezes the UI so I want to do it with the help of asynchronous call but I am not able to do that. CorePlot's delegates are called before the data is loaded. Please provide some tutorial or sample code. Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSurlconnection class to retrieve data from web ,
impliment the delegates of NSurlconnection class.

and do your drawing in connectiondidfinished delegate

Answer (score 1):

The *AAPLot* and *StockPlot* example apps included with Core Plot show how to do this. Until the plot data is available, return zero (0) from `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:`. When all of the data has been received from the web service, call `-reloadData` on the plot and return the correct plot data from the datasource.